# Apticron warns on held packages despite `NOTIFY_HOLDS=0`

Tags: untagged

```
$ sudo apt-cache show apticron
Package: apticron
Architecture: all
Version: 1.2.0
Priority: extra
Section: universe/admin
Origin: Ubuntu

$ sudo apt-mark showhold
linux-generic
linux-headers-generic
linux-image-generic

$ cat /etc/apticron/apticron.conf | grep NOTIFY_HOLDS | grep -v '#'
NOTIFY_HOLDS="0"
```

but `$ sudo apticron` still emails me

[image]

I can understand `linux-modules-*` showing up, but **shouldn't it be smart enough to suppress `linux-headers-*`  and `linux-image-*`?!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in Apticron which hasn't received enough attention yet. So the answer why this is happening (bug) and what can be done (nothing at this point but wait for the bug to be fixed or fix it yourself) is here: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=985795